# setting up nginx ldap authentication for Kibana 4

Tags: nginx, logstash, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I have setup ELK with kibana 4 and everything is running fine but I need LDAP integration so I recompiled nginx-1.7.9 with the nginx-auth-ldap-master module however I do not fully understand the syntax. Kibana is listening on port 5601 on localhost - the LDAP config is verified and correct but I am missing something. This is my Nginx config: (ELK config is standard)

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

   http {   

      auth_ldap_cache_enabled on;
      auth_ldap_cache_expiration_time 10000;
      auth_ldap_cache_size 1000;

 ##Configuration of your LDAP server
      ldap_server LDAP1 {
          url "ldaps://XXX:3268/dc=XX,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?";
          binddn "XX";
          binddn_passwd "XX";
          connect_timeout 5s;
          bind_timeout 5s;
          request_timeout 5s;
          satisfy any;
          group_attribute member;
          group_attribute_is_dn on;
          require group "CN=XX,OU=Grouper,OU=XX Groups,DC=XX,DC=com";
      }

      server {
        listen 80;

    server_name XX;

        auth_ldap "Please enter your ldap credentials";
        auth_ldap_servers LDAP1;


 location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;        
            }

        }       

   }
```

Would anyone be kind enough to see why this is returning "Unable to load the web page because the server sent no data." instead of Kibana ? (SElinux is disabled and ports are open on firewalld)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realised I was configuring it for LDAPS and I did not create ssl certs or point my nginx configuration towards the location of ssl certificates.